# Array cloning on access?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, performance, xna

I was reading XNA library code and inside the type `VertexPositionColor`, they supress the `CA2105:ArrayFieldsShouldNotBeReadOnly` message with the justification "The performance cost of cloning the array each time it is used is too great."

```
public struct VertexPositionColor
{
    public static readonly VertexElement [ ] VertexElements;
}
```

But why would it be copied when it's used? This only happens for structs where the accessed property/field is a `ValueType`, right?

Comment: Well, it is a game development library - performance wins out over strictly following the design rules. Also they changed the design of this feature [in XNA 4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/19/vertex-data-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) anyway.

Comment: I understand perf is more important but I don't know how this is making a copy by merely accessing the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess they are justifying the fact that they are exposing an `array` `field` more than anything else and the underlying reason of why they are doing so is performance:

The alternative they probably had in mind was making the `array` `field` private with a `property` exposing an `IEnumerable` or returning a copy of the `array` each time the `property` was accesed.

EDIT. Edited the answer a little to make clearer what I was trying to say :p.

Comment: Thanks, but why couldn't they just have a property that would pass the private array stored inside? That would do the same effect, no?

Comment: @Joan Venge: That would not provide a consistent `ref` which could be a problem depending on what they are doing with it.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by "consistent ref"? Are you saying this because of the static keyword?

Comment: Properties can not be `ref` parameters. That could be the reason.

Comment: I see but if they are passed by value, only the reference to the array would be copied, right? Not the whole array.

Comment: Now that I think about it though, passing a `readonly array` as a `ref` parameter doesn't make much sense as it is after all `readonly` (am I missing something?). I think the reason they didn't implement it as a `property` is because basically a `readonly array field` is essentially the same thing with a little micro performance gain.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases they'd be better off using [Array.AsReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53kysx7b.aspx) and returning a generic ReadOnlyCollection. According to the documentation that's an O(1) operation.

In the current implementation callers can change the values in the array (modifying the static/**global** state directly).

One more reason to read [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613) - it gives you the reasons behind FxCop's recommendations.

Comment: Thanks that's a pretty good idea. Didn't know about that method, seems like they should have used that like you said.